# Rearrange children of Scroll Container

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, starling-framework

I am trying to rearrange the children in a Scroll Container. I have a list collection with the same children and it is in the right order, all I need to do is take the scroll container and make the order of the children the same as the list collections order.

Here is what I am trying currently, the issue I am having is that some items end up in spots they shouldn't be.

```
menuListCollection.data = Array(e.data)[0];
for(var m:int = 0; m < menuListCollection.length; m++)
{
    var child:Object = cardScroller.getChildAt(m);
    trace(child.myPageID);
    if(menuListCollection.getItemAt(m).MobilePageID != child.myPageID)
    {
        for (var n:int = 0; n < menuListCollection.length; n++)
        {
            if(menuListCollection.getItemAt(n).MobilePageID == child.myPageID)
            {
                cardScroller.setChildIndex(DisplayObject(child), n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If any more details are needed, just ask and I can provide.

Thanks.

Comment: show your current code/markup related to the scroll container and list collection

Comment: I have added what I am currently doing to try and solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do it like this?

```
menuListCollection.data = Array(e.data)[0];
for(var m:int = 0; m < menuListCollection.length; m++)
{
    for (var n:int = 0; n < cardScroller.length; n++)
    {
        if(menuListCollection.getItemAt(m).MobilePageID == cardScroller.getChildAt(n).myPageID)
        {
            cardScroller.setChildIndex(DisplayObject(cardScroller.getChildAt(n)), m);
        }
    }
}
```